# Calculating packet loss, jitter and delay

Tags: android, metrics, delay, packet, rtsp

I am streaming an rtsp video to Android.
How could I calculate network metrics like packet loss, jitter or delay?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer that for packet loss and jitter.

For packet loss: Just count missed sequences. Keep the sequence of the last packet, and see if you have steps of more than 1. 
If you have reordering in your network, you will need to keep in a memory window previous sequences and fill it up as packets arrive, then check missed sequences.

For jitter - just keep the times where your client receives packets, and calculate the average difference between the actual received time and the expected received time of packets (assuming you can predict the expected receive time of packets - for example, if you have a constant FPS).

Comment: can you please let me know any code for that ?  how can i get that in android app ?

Answer (score 0):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) has RTP statistics calculation for sniffed packets.

Comment: I am looking for a way to get these statistics on an Android phone. (in real-time if possible)

Comment: I presume that you are not in control of the RSTP source, and cannot proxy the request through a source that you can sniff. I'll think on't.

Comment: I run a Darwin Streaming Server (DSS) but still I want to get these stats on the end-user device. Thanks.

Comment: Hi George, did you find how could measure the QoS parameters? I would be interested to see how you did.